# PHP print problems

Tags: php, html

hi I'm currently using a script to scan a directory for mp3 files and print the results with some other information surrounding each item found so i can populate a app that works fine however if i try to print something with <>  it doesn't show these

```
<?php
// *** requires PHP5 ***
// search for jpg files

$filter = ".mp3";
// url to be added to the path *** NO TRAILING SLASH ***
$url = 'http://********';
// path to the directory you want to scan
$directory = './';
$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("$directory");
foreach(new 

RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file)
{
  if (!((strpos(strtolower($file), $filter)) === false))
  {
    $items[] = preg_replace(array("#\\\#", "#./#"), array("/", "/"), $file);
  }
}
sort($items);

print <<<END
<music>
END;


foreach($items as $item)
{
  $title_array = explode('/', $item);
  $title = substr(end($title_array), 0, (strlen(end($title_array)) - 4));
  print <<<END


new AudioTrack(new Uri("$url$item",UriKind.Absolute), "$title", null, null, null),

END;
}


print <<<END
</music>


END;


?>
```

the code that I'm now wanting it to print is the same except in the print section I'm after

```
<print ><item>
<title>$title</title>
<link>$url$item</link>
<description>album name</description>
<guid isPermaLink="false">$url$item</guid>
<enclosure type="audio/mpeg" url="$url$item" />
</item>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Use htmlentities(), it should translate those characters into a safe format.  More info: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)